# Improving the Efficiency of an Idiosyncratic Volatility Function

Tags: r, regression

I have a function I wrote to calculate idiosyncratic volatility, but its really inefficient. Does anyone have any suggestions to make the code below more efficient?

Specifically, I am trying to take a time series and run a linear regression using a N_Max lookback. I then want to extract the residuals for the dates used in the linear regression and calculate the standard deviation. If there is not N_Max dates, I want to use as many dates as I have available provided it is larger than N_Min.

```
Idiosyncratic_Volatility <- function(dependent, independent, dates, Min_n, Max_n) {
  # Define size as the number of observations in the dependent
  size <- length(dependent)

  n <- Max_n

  # If the lookback is less than 0, stop the function and error out
  if (Min_n < 1 | Max_n < 1) stop("n must be positive")
  if (Max_n < Min_n) stop("Max_n must be greater than Min_n")

  # Define variables for the recursive function  
  i <- size                           # set the counter for itterations
  result <- NA; result[1:size] <- NA  # create a vector of NAs to store the results
  residuals_vector <- NA              # create a variable to store residuals

  while (i >= Max_n)
  {
    # Window is an R function that allows you to do run calculations over
    # desired rolling date ranges.
    RollingIndependent <- window(independent, start=i-n+1, end=i)
    RollingDependent  <- window(dependent, start=i-n+1, end=i)

    # If the data can cause an error, return NA
    if(
      n > length(RollingDependent) | 
        length(RollingDependent) > length(RollingIndependent) | 
        length(RollingDependent) > length(dates)) {
      result[i] <- NA

      # else calculate idiosyncratic volatility
    } else {  
      # fit a linear model to the data.
      model <- lm(RollingDependent ~ RollingIndependent)

      # extract the residuals from the model
      residuals_vector <- summary(model)$residuals

      # calculate the standard deviation of the residuals
      result[i] <- sd(residuals_vector,na.rm=FALSE)

      # iterate the recursive factor
      i <- i - 1
    }
  } 

  n <- i

  # This next part does the "burn in" period and runs off available information
  # until it hits the Min_n.
  while (i >= Min_n)
  {
    # Window is an R function that allows you to do run calculations over
    # desired rolling date ranges.
    RollingIndependent <- window(independent, start=i-n+1, end=i)
    RollingDependent  <- window(dependent, start=i-n+1, end=i)

    # If the data can cause an error, return NA
    if(
      n > length(RollingDependent) | 
        length(RollingDependent) > length(RollingIndependent) | 
        length(RollingDependent) > length(dates)) {
      result[i] <- NA

      # else calculate idiosyncratic volatility
    } else {  
      # fit a linear model to the data.
      model <- lm(RollingDependent ~ RollingIndependent)

      # extract the residuals from the model
      residuals_vector <- summary(model)$residuals

      # calculate the standard deviation of the residuals
      result[i] <- sd(residuals_vector,na.rm=FALSE)

      # iterate the recursive factor
      i <- i - 1
      n <- i
    }
  } 

  # print the results
  result
}
```

Thank you for your time!